# JavaScript, if statement always executes only the 'else' branch

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I've an `if` statement that test the value returned by a function call.
Even if the value is `true`, it always executes the `else` branch.

My code:

```
var debug = {
    enable: true,
    log: function(msg, tag){
        if(this.enable)
        console.log((tag?"["+tag+"] ":"") + msg);
    }
};

var checkUser = function(urlServer, user){
    $.couch.urlPrefix = urlServer;
    $.couch.login({
        name: user.name,
        password: user.password,
        success: function(data){
            debug.log("l'utente " + user.name + "è già registrato sul server", "checkUser");
            $.couch.logout({
                success: function(data){
                    debug.log("logout utente: OK", "checkUser");
                    debug.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    debug.log("logout utente: FAIL", "checkUser");
                    debug.log(data);
                }
            });
            return true
        },
        error: function(err){
            debug.log("l'utente " + user.name + " NON è registrato sul server", "checkUser");
            return false;
        },
        async: false
    });
};

// ... code ...

$("input").on("click", function(){
    if( checkUser(urlCouchDbServer, user) ){
        console.log("dopo il controllo l'utente risulta registrato");
    }else{
        console.log("dopo il controllo l'utente NON risulta registrato");
        sigupUser(urlCouchDbServer, user);
    }
});
```

Why this latest `if` does not work properly?
Thanks!

Comment: Your `checkUser()` doesn't return anything and `undefined` is interpreted as falsy, which executes the `else` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`checkUser` is doing something, but it is asynchronous. So, when you use it in the `if` statement returns `undefined` which is false. You should use callbacks to successfully write your logic. I.e.:

```
var checkUser = function(urlServer, user, callback) {
    // do something
    callback(true);
}

checkUser(..., ..., function(result) {
  if(result) {
     // ...
  } else {
     // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest using deferreds to keep the code more manageable but that is just technical